# While loop quickest method

Tags: time, logical-operators

Which is more quickly evaluated? I'm using java syntax, but any programming language would apply to the question.

```
while (1==1) {

}

while (true) {

}
```

I tried testing this with a large loop. The results varied far too much to give me a solid answer.

Comment: Remember the lesson: "the results varied far too much to give me a solid answer". Such micro-optimizations often have an unmeasurable impact. (Not counting that the behavior can depend on the circumstances.)

Comment: There is no general answer - it depends on the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a "micro optimisation". It's not worth it. Any decent compiler will produce identical code, since 1 == 1 is obviously the same as true. Even if it was different code, that little bit of change will not make any measurable difference.

Comment: you assume that the language is compiled - for an interpreted language it may make a difference (although I agree very unlikely to be material).

Answer (score 0):

While [@gnasher729's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36476651/1587329) is totally right for Java, here is how to find out by yourself.

See the following class file:

```
import java.util.Date;
public class SoOne {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        long counter = 1;
        long start = new Date().getTime();
        while ( 1 == 1 ) { // other class has while ( true )
            counter += 1;
            if ( counter % 1000000 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println("after: " 
                                   + ( new Date().getTime() - start )
                                   + ": " + counter
                                   + " per second: " 
                                   + ( counter
                                       / ( new Date().getTime() - start )));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you save this to f.ex. `SoOne.java`, change the line to `while (true)`, save it as `SoTrue.java`, and compile both via `javac SoOne.java SoTrue.java`, you get the class files. These can be disassembled via

```
 javap -c SoOne.class  >so.javap
 javap -c SoTrue.class  >st.javap
```

The differences are

```
 diff so.javap st.javap 
1,3c1,3
< Compiled from "SoOne.java"
< public class SoOne {
<   public SoOne();
---
> Compiled from "SoTrue.java"
> public class SoTrue {
>   public SoTrue();
```

So the compiler really removes both checks. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize about when to optimize.